# How to solve the error - NameError: variable @transition-speed is undefined?

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, less

I am new to less and scss. I am importing _variables.scss in header.less like this:

```
@import "../scss/variables";
```

I am getting the following error:

```
NameError: variable @transition-speed is undefined in header.less on line 12, column 29:

11  .navbar {
12    .transition(margin-left @transition-speed @transition-fn);
13    margin-bottom: 0;
```

The _variables.scss file looks like this:

```
$transition-speed: 0.3s !default;
```

The header.less file looks like this:

```
..........some other styling ...............
.navbar {
    .transition(margin-left @transition-speed @transition-fn);
    margin-bottom: 0;
..........some other styling ...............
}
```

I am using xampp.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't know. It shows the same error if I do not import _variables.scss.

Comment: I don't think you can import SCSS into LESS (or vice versa). Choose either SCSS _or_ LESS

Comment: If I choose less, it shows this error: `NameError: .transition is undefined`